# Need to make sure Thyristor switches off with rectified AC

Tags: voltage-regulator, dimmer, scr

So I have full-wave rectified AC from mains and the following circuit which is basically a AC dimmer that takes slices of that for a much lower total average voltage.

(Voltage source is labeled as an offsett-ed "triangle" below as I thought it approximates it best for now, damn simulation kit doesn't even have a bridge rectifier...)

Now, it's important that the Thyristor turn off at 0V of the rectified AC, so the cycle start anew of turning the Thyristor on and off. But I'm utterly unfamiliar with rectified AC and don't know if the current will absolutely 0A at 0V, though I know a resistor on AC is perfectly phased with voltage... I don't know, even maybe C1 or C2 might change the intended results...

Or, is it enough for me to pick a Thyristor whose Holding Current is in the hundred microamps range (or higher), so it cuts off??

EDIT:

Also, does C1 and C2 both have to have rating of at least 120V?? Don't they get charge on max up to 30-34V? That's specifically why I chose this design... I can choose lower rating capacitors...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbrgIL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The capacitance in that circuit won't affect the turnoff characteristic of an SCR.  An SCR will turn off whenever its anode current drops below its holding current. 
Check a datasheet for the Ih of the SCR device you are planning to use.  If you can't find a datasheet on the SCR, you can generally safely assume a maximum holding current of several mA for small devices, and 200mA for devices rated 10A and up.

As long as your rectified AC source actually can reach a 0V potential, with a resistive load, you shouldn't have any issues with the SCR turning off.  Even a simple reactive load shouldn't have any trouble turning off, since the effective voltage across the device would go reverse polarity as the reactive load dissipates its stored energy.

If you are working with very low power loads, you also need to make sure that the load will achieve the latching current of the SCR.  Typically the maximum latching current (Il) is about twice the holding current.  If you are trying to turn on the device, and it won't stay on, you need to increase your load.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer... Now for my other one... I don't really need the 2 capacitors to be rated at least at 120V, is it?

Comment: Yes, actually you do.  If the SCR is off, or even phased way back, the caps will see full line voltage across them.

Comment: I don't get it, when SCR is off, then there's 0V voltage across the capacitors, right?? And, what do you mean when "phased back"... Forgive my lack of knowledge...

Comment: If you pull the SCR out of the circuit, (or, it fails), you will see full voltage across the two capacitors.  If you go ahead and replace the diac with a phase control device to change the trigger point of the SCR's, it is also possible to see full peak voltage across the capacitors.  Mostly, I am concerned with failure modes, so I worry about if the SCR doesn't trigger.